# Selecting model based off of route in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations, rails-routing

I have a polymorphic model `Discussion`. It can be applied to `Specialty` model and `Program` model. My routes are set up as:

```
resources :programs, :only => :show do
   resources :discussions, :only => [:show, :create, :destroy, :new]
end

resources :specialties do
   resources :discussions, :only => [:show, :create, :destroy, :new]
end
```

So, new discussions are made either like:

```
 /specialties/yyyyy/discussions/new
 /programs/yyyyyy/discussions/new
```

The problem is in my `discussions_controller.rb` file. I have the function:

```
def new
  @object = xxxxx.find(params[:id])
end
```

How do I choose the appropriate model for the form (eg. to replace 'xxxxx') and for determining the discussionable_type. I would assume I could parse the URL, but it doesn't seem clean. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your routes, you should either have `params[:program_id]` or `params[:specialty_id]` (or alike).

This will tell you what to use.